# trying to understand history of xunit

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, xunit

"xUnit was written by the original inventor of nUnit v2."

https://xunit.github.io/

When was nUnit v2 written and when was xUnit written?  For example, was nUnit v2 completed in 05/2012 and xUnit completed in 09/2013?  What is the name of the original inventor of nUnit v2 and what was his rationale for creating xUnit?  Can you provide a url where this is documented? xUnit is open source so does the original author still oversee the project and merge in others' code updates at this point?

Answer (score 3):

I did some googling and was able to find the answer
http://jamesnewkirk.typepad.com/posts/2007/09/announcing-xuni.html